# Order By Count (someRecord)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a number of records. The columns are `Directory, Full Name, Server Name`. I would like a query to return a list of records that are sorted by the number of duplicate values of the Directory column.

**For Example:**

```
Directory      Full Name          Server Name
oneill         Liam O'Neill       server1
oneill         Liam O'Neill       server6
oneill         Liam O'Neill       server12
oneill         Liam O'Neill       server2
brown          Joe Brown          server4
brown          Joe Brown          server5
brown          Joe Brown          server2
walsh          Sarah Walsh        server1
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: In what way is your desired result different from your sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   full_name, server_name, COUNT(directory)
FROM     some_table
GROUP BY full_name, server_name
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it directly in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Directory d
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Directory d2
          WHERE d.Directory = d2.Directory) DESC
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e9df/5/0)</kbd>

Change `DESC` to `ASC` if you want to sort ascending, so that the directories with less duplicates come first. Your sample not as good since you've already sorted it by duplicates(desc).

Comment: Depends on if there's an index on `Directory` or not. In general correlated subqueries do not need to execute once per row always. As you can see on the query plan of above query the stream aggregate also groups by directory even with this little sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e9df/6/0

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions for this:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by Directory) as cnt
from table t
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: What's the benefit of the window function here as compared to a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` sub-query?

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . The advantage is that windows functions are specifically designed for this purpose.  They *should* be more optimized (I'm not saying they actually are).  If performance is a concern, then it is best to test different versions.